# how to make Andriod APP base on kaa SDK

Tags: publish, kaa

I studied the Android samples in GitHub and the Kaa sandbox, and noticed that those apps are standardized and can not be changed.

Then I tried to build-up my own Android app base on the library in the downloaded SDK, but didn't find out a way.

Can you help with the following ?

1. Which Android developing tool (IDE) is recommend to develop Kaa Android apps?
2. How can I make my Android app downloadable in sandbox web page?
3. How can I publish it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use any one IDE for the development of your own Android application with or without use of Kaa SDK. Kaa does not provide any recommendations usually. But, we use IDEA Studio at the moment.
2. You should not normally add any applications to the Kaa Sandbox. This is complex and requires many steps to do.

But, you can contribute your application to the [Sample Apps GitHub](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps) repository. This way, it might be included into one of the next future Kaa Sandbox releases.

3. To publish your Android application, you can do any combination of the next:

   - Contribute the application to the Sample Applications repository on GitHub so it might be included into the future Kaa Sandbox releases
   - Publish your application on Google Play Market just as any other Android application so it will be publicly available for all Android users.

**Note**: Due to the nature of the Kaa SDK emdedded into the Kaa-based Android applications, the published application will be bound to one Kaa server (or cluster) the SDK was generated on. This applies some limitations on the Android applications published to the Google Play Market.